# Convert string in textbox to datetime column in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

Good day. 
I'm very newbie in asp.net/c#/linq/etc, and I'm  trying to figure it all out.
But it's need to do one small project.

In my view I have a table with datetime/string values and i need to insert this values to mssql database.

On View I have several Html.TextBox'es. By clicking button, TextBox is filled by current datetime.
View header(JS):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function setDate(boxID) {
            var dateNow = new Date();
            var dd = dateNow.getDate();
            var mm = dateNow.getMonth() + 1;
            var yy = dateNow.getFullYear();
            var hh = dateNow.getHours();
            var MM = dateNow.getMinutes();
            var ss = dateNow.getSeconds();
            if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
            if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
            if (MM < 10) { MM = '0' + MM }
            if (ss < 10) { ss = '0' + ss }
            var today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yy + ' ' + hh + ':' + MM + ':' + ss;
            document.getElementById(boxID).value = today;
        }
    </script>
```

View body:

```
<div class="divTableCell">
   @Html.TextBox("p1_t1")
   <input type="button" value="OK" onclick='setDate("p1_t1")' />
</div>
<div class="divTableCell">
    @Html.TextBox("p1_notice")
</div>
<button id="result "type="submit">Insert data</button>
```

By clicking the last button i'm trying to insert this values to external database. Table contains columns p1_notice varchar(250) and p1_t1 datetime;

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EntranceInspection()
{
    return View();
}

EntranceInspectionTableDataContext d = new EntranceInspectionTableDataContext();

public ActionResult EntranceInspectionResult()
{

    EntranceInspection s = new EntranceInspection();
    s.p1_notice = Request["p1_notice"]; // to SQL - ok
    s.p1_t1 = Request["p1_t1"]; // error convert string to datetime
    d.EntranceInspection.InsertOnSubmit(s);
    d.SubmitChanges();
    return View("EntranceInspection");
}
```

Is there any acceptable way to convert value in textbox to datetime and insert to datetime-column? Or I need to do something different at the start?

Thx

Comment: just use s.p1_t1 =  Convert.ToDateTime(Request["p1_t1"]);

Comment: thanks a lot, it's works for me.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try the following code ,

```
 public ActionResult EntranceInspectionResult()
    {
        EntranceInspection s = new EntranceInspection();
        s.p1_notice = Request["p1_notice"]; // to SQL - ok
        s.p1_t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["p1_t1"]); 
        d.EntranceInspection.InsertOnSubmit(s);
        d.SubmitChanges();
        return View("EntranceInspection");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type cast the text value into the datetime like below.

```
s.p1_t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["p1_t1"]);
```

This will help you to insert datetime value in database without error.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the text value into the datetime thus:

```
s.p1_t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["p1_t1"]);
```

This will help you to insert datetime value in database without error. But, maybe can be usefull you garantie that p1_t1 has not a null value if in database the field is not nullabe.
If it is nullabe, you should insert datemin value or other value that is logical for your business.

Comment: thx, for null-values I added function with DateTime ? type which checks for nulls.